# C++ compile-time / runtime options and parameters, how to handle?

Tags: c++, c++11, runtime, compile-time

What is the proper way to handle compile-time and runtime options in a generic library? What is good practice for large software in which there are simply too many options for the user to bother about most of them?

Suppose the task is to write a large library to perform calculations on a number of datasets at the same time. There are numerous ways to perform these calculations, and the library must be be highly configurable. Typically, there are options relative to how the calculation is performed as a whole. Then, each dataset has its own set of calculation options. Finally, each calculation has a number of tuning parameters, which must be set as well.

The library itself is generic, but each application which uses that library will use a particular kind of dataset, for which tuning parameters will take on a certain value. Since they will not change throughout the life of the application, I make them known at application **compile-time**. The way I would implement these tuning parameters in the library is through a `Traits` class, which contains the tuning parameters as `static const` elements. Calibration of their final value is part of the development of the application.

The datasets will of course change depending on what the user feeds to the application, and therefore a number of **runtime** options must be provided as well (with intelligent defaults). Calibration of their default value is also part of the development of the application. I would implement these options as a `Config` class which contains these options, and can be changed on application startup (e.g. parsing a config text file). It gets passed to the constructor of a lot of the classes in the library. Each class then calls the `Config::get_x` for their specific option `x`.

The thing I don't really like about this design, is that both `Traits` and `Config` classes break encapsulation. Some options relate to some parts of the library. Most of the time, however, they don't. And having them suddenly next to each other annoys me, because they affect separate things in the code, which are often in different abstraction layers.

One solution I was thinking about, is using multiple public inheritance for these different parts. A class which needs to know an option then casts the `Config` object or calls the relevant `Trait` parent to access it. Also, this passing along of `Config` to every class that needs it (or whose members need it) is very inelegant. Maybe `Config` should be a singleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have your parameters in a single struct named Config (to keep your words) and make it a singleton.

Encapsulation is important to preserve classes consistency, because a class is responsible of itself. But in your case where the Config class must be accessible to everyone, it is necessary. Furthermore, adding getters and setters to this type of class will only add overhead (in the best case you compiler will probably just inlined it).

Also, if you really want a Traits class to implement compile time parameters, you should probably just have an initialization function (like the constructor of your library).

Comment: Welcome to SO! I guess you mean encapsulation is *not* necessary for Config (typo?). About the Traits, you seem to dislike it. Any reason why?

Comment: I don't necessarily dislike, furthermore I love telling everyone to respect it. But the specific goal of your case is to have a class accessible to everyone. So encapsulation seems a bit useless in this case. If you want to respect it anyway, use friends classes but if all of your classes are friends, it is pointless.